# C : getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c

so I've been teaching myself C and I've come across the 'getchar()' and 'putchar()' methods from 'stdio.h'. As I understand it, 'getchar()' takes the most recent character from the text stream and stores it into a variable whilst 'putchar()' takes this variable and prints it to the terminal.

So I've written the following piece of code:

```
    #import<stdio.h>

void main () {
    printf("Enter a character and it will be repeated back to you:\n");
    int c;
    while (c != EOF) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("You entered : ");
        putchar(c);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and I expected it to read the keyboard input and print it to the screen one character at a time. As an example, if I were to type "home", the output would be:

You entered : h
You entered : o
You entered : m
You entered : e

but instead i get:

home
You entered : h
You entered : o
You entered : m
You entered : e

The characters are printed as im typing and then repeated afterwards. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here or if I am doing anything wrong and just don't quite grasp the concept. Can anyone explain whats happening here?

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior, since `c` is uninitialized the first time it's used.  You will also pass `EOF` to `putchar` when you read it, which you shouldn't do.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If you have a book that tells you to use `void main()`, its author doesn't know C well enough to be writing about it. (Unless it's referring to some specific freestanding implementation, but that's unlikely.)

Comment: The book is written Brian W, Kercnighan and Dennis M. Ritchie. At the moment, the main function is just "main(){}" but i added the void because I have experiencec with C# and return types and stuff like that.

Comment: You will get more mileage out of `#include <stdio.h>`. Leave `import` to python...

Comment: back in the days of K and R, the returned type defaulted to `int`, however, in modern C, that is a problem and you have to explicitly state: `int` as the returned type

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: There is no `import` in C...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin then why does my above code work?

Comment: No clue, the closest thing to `"import"` in the C11 Standard is `"important"` in [Footnote 234](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note234) there is no other occurrence in the standard. What reference do you rely on showing `#import` is the proper way to include a header file? See [C11 Standard - 5.1.1.1 Program structure](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.1) and [5.1.1.2 Translation phases - No. 4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2p1)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ah right, sheer dumb luck then. Do you have any tips for learning the language?

Comment: I'll go with that -- not 100% reliable, but.... may work every once in a while `:)` Yes -- *slow down*.. Learning C isn't a race, it's more of a journey. Every character you type in each line has a purpose. Every byte of memory you use must be accounted for and validly available for your use. It takes time to understand the nuances of the language, but there is no better language to learn and learning C will make you a better programmer regardless of what you ultimately end up writing in. So how do you learn C? The same way you eat a whale -- one byte at a time, Enjoy the journey `:)`

Comment: Practical tips - look at the man-page for every function you use to know the proper use, parameter types, return type and error conditions associated with it. (e.g. [man7.org man-pages online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html)). Spend 1-hr. wtih the `scanf` man page and learn it -- it will save you 10-fold hours later. Use line-oriented input functions `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) for user-input. **Check the return** of every function that can succeed or fail. Especially EVERY input. Write short test code, then put the pieces together. Stay on StackOverflow!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks man, I've been trying to learn quickly instead of taking my tearn and actually understanding what I've written. Plus, I love the pun at the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output you're getting is expected.

Unless you make use of OS-specific functions to change the terminal settings, terminal input is only made available to the application when you enter a full line. The terminal driver buffers lines to allow you to edit before submitting it, and it echoes your input as you're typing it.

Once the line is entered, each call to `getchar()` retrieves one character from the line (as well as the final newline).

However, there *is* a bug in your program unrelated to your question. You're testing `c` before you assign it the first time. Also, the `c != EOF` test is checking the input from the previous iteration, which already tried to print that input, but you can't print `EOF`.

A better way to write the loop would be:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("You entered : ");
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or if the combined assignment and test is confusing, you can do:

```
while (1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    puts("You entered: ");
    putchar(c);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, I was concentrating only on the question about the input processing. I've updated the answer to show how to fix that.

Comment: Thank you, I was worried I was doing something wrong. I've also fixed that issue with the unassigned variable.